# Googlemaps javascript api zoom control +/- signs dissapear

Tags: javascript, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-api-3

I have to fix a display problem in an interactive online map that uses the Google Maps Javascript API. The problem is that the +/- signs to zoom appear a fraction of a second when the page is initially loaded but then disappear. Here is the link URL of the map:

https://www.ctq.gouv.qc.ca/fileadmin/documents/CarteInteractive/carte.html

If anyone has an insigh on how to adress that problem, that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is the buttom has the opacity:0 so you could'nt see it for this reason. If you want to solve it you need check the API parameters and check if you need some paramaters or remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the buttom has the opacity:0 so you could'nt see it for this reason. If you want to solve it you need check the API parameters and check if you need some paramaters or remove it.

Comment: Thank you!, As a follow up, the bug was coming from a snippet of code that had been added previously to correct a control bug on IE 10.